# idea: set default test (runner) configuration?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, intellij-plugin, test-runner, kotest

Idea offers different (test run) configurations, e.g. with the runners Gradle, JUnit and Kotest:
[image: (Runner)Configurations]

**How do I set the default runner**, e.g. to Kotest, which is created when I click on `Run myTest`?

[image: Run Test]
Currently, my maven project by default creates Kotest run configurations for tests, my Gradle project Gradle run configurations.

This question does *not* regard configuration templates.

Answer (score 0):

The default runner (either Gradle or IntelliJ) can be chosen here:
[image]

Comment: this is not the **test** runner